# Почему "--" превращается в длинное тире?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

В Телеграм боте меню выбора языка.
Строка en --> English должна разделяться на две половинки:

```
String[] parts = message.getText().split("-->", 2);
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку две черточки сливаются в одну длинную:

en —> English

и разделить строку не получается. Что с этим делать?
Скриншоты прилагаю. Буду оч признателен за помощь.

[image: скриншот1]

[image: скриншот2]

Comment: при нажатии на какую кнопку?

Comment: На кнопку меню выбора языка. На скриншоте их 4 видно

Comment: я не сильно знаком с телеграм ботами. На каком этапе меняется черточка, она к вашему боту приходит как одна или внутри бота меняется?

Comment: Если не сильно знакомы с телеграм ботами, врядли поможете решить проблемку. Спасибо за участие.

Comment: Вроде как типографская фича клиента. Хотя, наверно, при нажатии на кнопку типографские фичи работать не должны, возможно есть смысл багрепорт отправить

Answer (score 1):

В качестве workaround я просто заменил в тексте кнопок два тире на одно, тогда все работает как надо.

```
String[] parts = message.getText().split("->", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю ,как сейчас,но на первых порах,в телеге проблемы графического отображения решал копипастом требуемых символов из "библиотеки символов" на windows.Т.е вместо ручного ввода в коде,просто копипаста.